# iOS: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill is not applied (not working) on some images

Tags: ios

I am seeing some strange behavior where UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill contentMode is correctly set on some images but NOT on others.  This is how I am setting the images:

```
  self.photos = @[ [UIImage imageNamed:@“pic1.jpg"],  [UIImage imageNamed:@“pic2.jpg"]];

  for (int i = 0; i < self.photos.count; i++)
  {
    UIImageView *picView = [UIImageView new];
    picView.image = self.photos[i];
    picView.frame = Frame(1080.0 * i,0,1080.0,self.picHeight);
    picView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    picView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.photoScrollView addSubview:picView];
  }
```

This is the pic1.jpg where UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill is NOT honored and the pic is squished  vertically:
[image]ic2.jpg

This is pic2.jpg where UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill does what it should. Same code for both images.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This really feels like a bug on Apple's end, but I did find a very simple work around.

After adding the UIImageView to its superview, I just do this which gets the UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill to work:

```
picView.frame = CGRectMake(picView.frame.origin.x, picView.frame.origin.y, picView.frame.size.width, picView.frame.size.height + 1);
```